# How to set the Taskbar Grouping Icon

Tags: .net, winforms, icons, grouping, taskbar

When my application opens too many windows the taskbar groups them into one button. Each window has its own icon, but the grouping icon is the default "unknown"-kind icon.

How can I set the grouping icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [comment from Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/04/08/109775.aspx#124579) indicates that the icon is coming from the exe itself, I would suggest using something like [eXeScope](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA003525/Eindex.htm) to make sure that your application icon is being embedded properly, and maybe compare it with other exes that display proper behavior to do delta debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The taskbar group icon can be set in the registry on a per application basis.

For explorer, this would be here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\explorer.exe]
"TaskbarGroupIcon"="C:\Windows\Explorer.exe,13"
```

Comment: It seems that Explorer.exe is the only application on my computer that is registered in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications". Other apps (including Outlook) do have a correct icon, but they don't have a "TaskbarGroupIcon" value...

Answer (score 1):

Application taskbar group icon can be set in two ways

1. Through Project Properties:

   Click Project in solution explorer → right click → select properties → select Application tab → go to resoruces and change the default icon and select the newicon and save and build.
2. Through Registry(Dynamic):

   You have to create TaskbarGroupIcon key and value is "icon file with path" under 
   "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\<>"
   If above keys are not present you have to create

   ```
   RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
      "Software\\Classes\\Applications\temp.exe",true); 
   RegKey.SetValue("TaskbarGroupIcon", "c:\temp.ico", RegistryValueKind.String);
   ```