# How can I change the icons used in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell Icon Overlay (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843506/shell-icon-overlay-c)

Tortoise changes the icons so you know what files have been changed locally. That's what I want to do.

I want to write an app that changes the icon for an app under certain conditions.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck? Do you want to change the whole icon, or just an icon overlay?

Comment: Did not even know where to start. Yes, I think it's a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use something other than C# to implement a shell extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called shell extensions, and [Microsoft recommends against writing them in managed code](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/587815/managed-net-4-shell-extension-hangs-explorer-only-in-xp-on-shutdown).

Here is [official MSDN documentation on how to create icon overlays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Also look at:

- [How to change the icon for a shortcut on the desktop in C# 2.0?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/ce3ba993-2578-48b5-acb4-5421af950b05)
- [Programmatically change the icon of the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539095/programmatically-change-the-icon-of-the-executable)