# Applications icon is changing on pinning it into taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have used icon property for my main window and whenever my application runs it shows that icon but if I pin my aapplication into taskbar icon gets changed and shows Windows command prompt icon.

Comment: Application have it's icon which is shown in taskbar, in explorer etc. You can change that icon by selecting properties of your WPF project. Icon(s) put on windows are different icons.

Comment: I tried putting icon on project properties but it is always showing error that icon is too small and load failed.

Comment: i think icon has to be at least 32x32 px

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change pinned taskbar icon (windows 7)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969033/change-pinned-taskbar-icon-windows-7)

Comment: Where did you get the icon from? Did you look into its levels? Icons can have various sizes and display the one that most closely fits. It is easy to create one the looks entirely diiferent at different sizes. Greefish is a tool to look into it and edit it.. VS used to do it too, some time ago..

Answer (score 2):

If anyone would need it.

To get the icon the taskbar same as the one you set to the form. 1. Go to your project properties 2. Choose 'Application' 3. At Resources, choose 'Icon and manifest' 4. Set your chosen icon.